# Getting default value for certain DataType in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there any way to get default value having `DataType`?

By "default" I mean something similar to Golang:

```golang
var message string
// Default value: ""

var age int
// Default value: 0

var isValid bool
// Default value: false
```

I was trying to do it in Julia in a same way:

```
function get_default_value(t::DataType)
    x::t
    return x
end

function main()
    println(get_default_value(Integer))
end

main()
```

but got `UndefVarError: x not defined`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

One misconception that I want to clarify first is that `x::Int` is not defining a new `Int` variable called `x`, it's an assertion that the value `x` contains is of `Int` type. That line is *not* creating a new variable called `x`.

Also, variables themselves don't usually have an inherent type in Julia, and so you can't have default values for variables. (There are [a couple of ways](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Declarations) to declare a variable as holding only values of a particular type, but even those only declare the variable names, without defining them into existence; and so, there's no default values there either.)

The functions I've mentioned below operate on types, and are defining 'additive identity' and 'multiplicative identity' rather than a default value. When other languages give a default value to their variables, they usually tend to use the additive identity of that type, so it works out that `zero` fills in that role in most cases.

So, to get results similar to the ones you've mentioned, `zero` works for numeric types, `Date` types, etc.

```
julia> zero(Dates.Time)
0 nanoseconds

julia> zero(Bool)
false

julia> zero(Int)
0

julia> zero(Float64)
0.0
```

`zero` isn't defined for `String` type though, for that you use the `one` method:

```
julia> one(String)
""

julia> one(Int)
1

julia> one(Bool)
true
```

The reason is that string concatenation in Julia is done with the `*` operator, and `one` is the function in Julia that returns the identity ("default") value for `*`.

There's also the `oneunit` function that's useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to know that `zero` is defined for given DataType before calling it?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `hasmethod` function: `hasmethod(zero, Tuple{String})` returns `false`, and `hasmethod(one, Tuple{String})` returns `true`.

Comment: I suggest underlining the main answer to this question: there _are_ no default values for most types in Julia. Only if a method `T()` for type `T`, is there something like that. `zero` is a reasonable surrogate, but it's not really a default value.

Comment: @DNF I've rearranged the answer based on your suggestion, thanks.